# Is there an axiomatic set theory that limits cardinality, not rank?

Tags: set-theory

In the usual explanation of the set/class distinction, we say that the former is 'too large' to be a set. But, too large in what sense? Rank or cardinality? For example, the class of all sets (call it $V$) has both large rank and large cardinality. So $V$ is clearly not a set. But what about concepts like $\{V\}$? Note that, although $\{V\}$ has large rank, it has small cardinality.

**Question**. Is there an axiomatic set theory that permits entities like $V$ (a proper class) and $\{V\}$ (a 'set' according to this approach), while disallowed entities like $\mathcal{P}(V)$ that would have strictly greater than proper-class cardinality?

Comment: Note that $V$ is not a set even if we don't assume the axiom of regularity, in which case we cannot define a rank function. Furthermore if $\mathcal P$ is a the power set operation, then $\mathcal P(X)=\{A\subseteq X\mid A\text{ is a set}\}$, which means that $\mathcal P(V)=V$. Lastly, if $\{V\}$ is a set then we violate the axiom of replacement in a very severe way way, as well the axiom of union.

Comment: To add on my previous comment, in order to "permit entities to exist" we essentially say that something is a set, or in a class-set theory that it might be a class as well. But if you already permit classes, then you also permit $V$ to exist.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence in the first comment. How is replacement violated?

Comment: Oh yeah, scratch that part. I made a mistake there. (I'm leaving the comment because there are other parts I'm too lazy to rewrite :-))

Comment: If you define $\mathcal{P}(X) = \{A \subseteq X \mid A \mbox{ is a class }\}$ then what I wrote about disallowed $\mathcal{P}(V)$ makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the whole point of classes is to talk about "definable collections" rather than actual objects. Yes, we can formally introduce them as objects using things like NBG or MK, but their purpose is still to give us an auxiliary method of talking about collections of "main objects".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, sure, but it would be cool to be able to stick them into sets, no? I'm more curious as to whether it can be done more than anything.

Comment: You may want to read about $\sf NF$ which has a universal set. So $\{V\}$ exists, but $\mathcal P(V)$ in the sense that you wrote don't (however in the sense that I wrote it does).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, if you're interested, I just noticed that any theory along the lines of what I was asking in this question will be inconsistent. For instance, the following very reasonable looking axioms yield Russell's paradox. (0) (Classes and Sets) Every class is a set. (1) (Comprehension) Given a definable predicate $P$, the class of all sets satisfying $P$ exists. (2) (Unions) For all classes $C$, there exists a class $U$ such that for all $x$ we have $x \in U$ iff $x \in X$ for some $X \in C$. (3) (Singletons) For all classes $X$, there exists a set $Y$ whose sole element is $X$.

Comment: So basically, we prove the existence of $\{\{X\} \mid X \mbox{ is a class}, X \notin X\}$ and then take a union. We don't write it like this, though, because there's no axiom of extensionality.

Comment: But we already came to the obvious conclusion that we don't have the axiom of union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, we did?

Comment: Of course. $\{V\}$ is a set, but $V$ is a class so it is impossible that $\bigcup\{V\}$ is a set.

Comment: In the axioms I wrote down, we don't assume $\bigcup \{V\}$ is a set, only that its a class.

Comment: In fact we just call the entities in our domain of discourse 'classes', we don't need axiom 0.

Comment: Well, your comment is not very careful anyway. You wrote that any theory would be inconsistent, then you gave one possible theory. But I think that unions are off the table completely if you want this sort of shtick. *Maybe* you can require that the union of a class that all its members are pure sets is a class, or something like that, and that if this is a set then the result is a set as well. I don't see why comprehension enters the story, that's playing with fire after dousing yourself in kerosine.

Comment: Well, if not comprehension, then what principle would you suggest for proving that various classes exist? I thought the whole point of classes is that we get back comprehension, with the caveat being that the things we collected together needn't form a set.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying. You're basically saying, 'restrict comprehension to classes that can be injected into the class of all pure sets.' I didn't think of that.

Comment: Yes, it is true. But at the same time you don't allow classes to be members of other classes (or sets) for that reason. If you want to allow comprehension again you need to set some limitation. For example, you can start by restricting comprehension to classes of pure sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yeah I think I get what you're saying.

Comment: You're the first! ;-)

Comment: Note, however, that if you do start imposing limitations you are likely to end up with the following situation: $V$ is the class of all sets, but $W$ is the actual universe and $V\subsetneq W$; and $\{W\}$ doesn't exist. So you will have to add another level of "$2$-classes" and so on and so forth. Even at the limit stage of $\omega$ steps you won't have $\{W\}$ for the actual universe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yeah that's what I was thinking, but hopefully there's a way around it. After all, $\{W\}$ only has one element, so it should definitely exist.

Comment: Yes, but $W$ is not a class anymore.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, nevertheless, if $W$ exists, then I think we want $\{W\}$ to exist. In general, we should be allowed to think of everything as an atom.

Comment: But that's the point, $W$ doesn't exist. Things which exist are objects of the universe, not subsets (read: subclasses) of the universe. I think that $\sf NF$ is really an answer to your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yeah I've downloaded Randall Holmes free ebook on NFU so I'll know more about it pretty soon. As for $W$, well if it doesn't exist then of course neither does $\{W\}.$ But, why shouldn't it exist? In general, I we prefer the idea that "you cannot do action $A$ to object $X$" rather than "object $X$ does not exist."

Comment: Well, if you approach this problem as "well, $\sf ZFC$ is pretty nice, so let's require that the class of hereditarily pure sets behaves at least to some degree like a model of $\sf ZFC$", in which case you may want to require that the classes over those sets behave a bit like a model of $\sf NBG$, and so on. You end up with the same result as Russell's paradox: the collection of all objects is not an object itself.

Comment: Don't you just end up with TG? (Which, btw, isn't what I'm looking for).

Comment: And still, in $\sf TG+Universes$, the class of all objects is not an object.

Comment: Yeah, but anyway, the class of all objects doesnt imply Russell's paradox unless we have class separation. Which we kind of want. Okay.... now i see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 2):

There are axiomatic set theories that limit cardinality, most often by simply eliminating the axiom of the power set. For example the [hereditarily countable sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_countable_set) form a model of Kripke-Platek set theory.

Even in such theories, $\{V\}$ will not exist, because although that set has small cardinality, it has large "hereditary cardinality" - meaning that its transitive closure has large cardinality. It turns out that, for these purposes, the hereditary cardinality is more useful than the actual cardinality for telling whether a set is "small".

Comment: I think that the issue here is that we expect the notion of set to be at least somewhat "transitive" (and in particular in pure set theories), so elements of sets are sets, and so on. Therefore having $\{V\}$ as a set but $V$ as a proper class is an inherent contradiction.

Comment: Carl, the essence of the question I was trying to ask is, 'Is there a set theory where only size, and not hereditary size, are limited?' So whether by 'hereditary size' we mean 'rank' or 'hereditary cardinality' isn't really the critical factor.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that's just a terminological thing. We can distinguish between 'pure' sets like $\{\emptyset\}$ and impure sets like $\{\emptyset,V\}$ if we like, or we can design our terminology differently. Either way, if we allow collections of small cardinality, whose elements may have large cardinality, then the class of all collections of small cardinality won't be transitive. But, is this really an issue? If we want to do transfinite recursion, we can just stick to pure sets.

Comment: @user18921: Of course this is a terminological thing. But on a much more fundamental level, the word "set" is a terminological thing. We give it to objects which behave according to some list of axioms which we expect sets to have. And before we even approach that point, I think, some sort of hereditary property of "being an object" seems needed. But let's see what axioms fail badly in this sort of set theory: union and regularity, not to mention that you have to have classes in this theory, otherwise the formula $V\in\{V\}$ is meaningless. It's unclear whether replacement and power set hold.